# mysql, calculate min value for all users

Tags: mysql

I have a table of users id and their activity time stamps. two columns. I would like to get a table of people and their maximum and minimum timestamps.

I know how to get min and max for individuals but not for all:

```
select min(tb_timestamp), max(tb_timestamp) from tb
where tb_user_id=10;
```

Comment: Instead of "where clause" use a group by on "tb_user_id" and you will get the two attributes for all the users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
    MIN(tb_timestamp), MAX(tb_timestamp)
FROM
    tb
GROUP BY tb_user_id
```

Answer (score 5):

Aggregate functions often need a GROUP BY statement.

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_name;
```

So do this:

```
SELECT MIN(tb_timestamp), MAX(tb_timestamp)
FROM tb
GROUP BY tb_user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY`.It will work

```
select min(tb_timestamp), max(tb_timestamp) from tb
GROUP BY tb_user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead ,

```
SELECT MIN(tb_timestamp), MAX(tb_timestamp) FROM tb
GROUP BY tb_user_id
```